# Setting up my mx records with Office365

Tags: microsoft-office, domain, office365

I purchased a O365 Personal subscription.
I own a domain controlled by a website provider, and I went to their site and set mail to be hosted by Office 365.

A warning notified me that I probably needed to manually change the MX and a TXT record in my Domain DNS settings.

**So here is my problem:**
All guides I find online about getting the MX record etc. require me to go to
the Admin Center.
Such as this:

[Microsoft Guide to getting the mx record](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/get-help-with-domains/information-for-dns-records?view=o365-worldwide)

Now I know what the admin Center is cause at work I'm an administrator and often use it.
But my Office 365 Personal don't have an admin center, it isn't there under apps.

I have no idea if the subscription I purchased simply isn't capable of handling a domain, but I feel like that would be weird.

I don't really know how to proceed.
Currently I changed my MX record to
"myownprivatedomain.mail.protection.outlook.com'

and txt to: 
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:spf."myhostingprovider".com -all

Comment: a friend tells me that he connects a domain with his personal o365 but the domain have to host by godaddy.

Comment: I read that about purchasing a new domain, but this one I have.. and own allready